# Is min-width required on a nested list?

Tags: html, css

I have a nested list like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="">Parent Links</a>
      <!-- Flyoutwrapper is what expands when users hover over the parent links, the contents of flyoutwrapper will be changing, so I can not set a min-width or width -->
      <div class="flyoutWrapper">
        <ul class="flyout fourCol">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want all the li's inside of class="flyout fourCol" to float next to each other. In columns. But unless I set a min-width of ~900px for "flyout fourCol" each li element collapses below the previous one.

This is what I want my dropdown to look like:

```
#nav .flyout.fourCol { min-width:900px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t7esz/ (this works)

```
#nav .flyout.fourCol { width:auto; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sumcA/2/ (this doesn't work!)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, yes, because your `.flyout` submenu is inheriting the width from its parent, your "weddings" `li`, which does not have a width of `900px`. If you remove the width from your `flyout` div and add it to your "weddings" parent `li` your submenu will inherit that same width and will not need to be explicitly given a width. So your answer is yes, you need to add a width to your submenu in order to conform to its own width, otherwise it will be inherited from the parent.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestions for restructuring this HTML so that I don't ever have to set explicit widths?

Comment: @illusorydeveloper You can unfloat your parent `li` and it should take the width of its parent (when properly clearfixed) and then just float your child `li`s to the left, though that would render unwanted results so you will have better luck just adding a `min-width`, but here is a demo without any width declarations:  http://jsfiddle.net/sumcA/3/